# What is the fastest way to group my records?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

My site shows collections of links on different subjects. These links are divided into two types: web and images. My database will have millions (probably more than ten million) of these records. When the page loads, I need to show the user the web and image links for the particular subject of that page. So the first question is:

1. Do I create two separate, smaller tables, one each for the web and image links, and then make a query to each, or do I create one huge table (with correct indexes) for both and make one query. Where will I get better performance? Should the one table and one query be more efficient, then my next question is:
2. What would be the most efficient way to subdivide the two types for presentation? Should I use `group by`, or should I use php to divide my result array into the two types?

TIA!

Comment: I don't find very clear what you want to achieve. Is it a list of the types first, and then, when the user chooses one, a list of the elements of each type?

Comment: It show all the links for both types. I'll update the question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible you'll get *slightly* better performance from just one table, but this decision should be primarily guided by whether the nature of data or constraints is different or not.

There is another (more important from the performance perspective) decision you'll have to make: how do you want to [cluster](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index) the data (all [InnoDB tables are clustered](http://www.ovaistariq.net/521/understanding-innodb-clustered-indexes/))?

If you want to have an excellent performance getting all the links of a given page, use an identifying relationship, producing a natural key in the link table(s):

[image]

The LINK table is effectively just a single B-tree, with the page PK<sup>1</sup> at its **leading edge**, which physically groups together the rows that belong to the same page. The following query can be satisfied by a simple index range scan and minimal I/O:

```
SELECT URL
FROM LINK
WHERE PAGE_ID = <whatever>
```

If you used separate tables, you can just have two different queries. Many client APIs support executing two queries in a single database round-trip. If PHP doesn't, you can UNION the two queries to save one database round-trip:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 1 LINK_TYPE, URL
    FROM IMAGE_LINK
    WHERE PAGE_ID = <whatever>
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, URL
    FROM WEB_LINK
    WHERE PAGE_ID = <whatever>
)
ORDER BY LINK_TYPE
```

The above query will give you...

```
LINK_TYPE  URL
1          http://somesite.com/foo.jpeg
1          http://somesite.com/bar.jpeg
1          http://somesite.com/baz.jpeg
...
2          http://somesite.com/foo.html
2          http://somesite.com/bar.html
2          http://somesite.com/baz.html
...
```

...which will be very easy to separate at the client level.

If you didn't use separate tables, you can them separate the URLs by their extension at the client level, or introduce an additional field in the LINK PK: {PAGE_ID, LINK_TYPE, URL}, which should make the following query very efficient:

```
SELECT LINK_TYPE, URL
FROM LINK
WHERE PAGE_ID = <whatever>
ORDER BY LINK_TYPE
```

Note that the order of fields in the PK matters, so placing the LINK_TYPE at the end would prevent the DBMS from *just* doing the index range scan.

---

*<sup>1</sup> Whatever it may be; I just used the `PAGE_ID` as an example.*

Comment: Thanks for an extremely informative answer! I had a question on the beginning, however: if I would use the page_id as my PK, wouldn't that limit me to only one url in the link table per page? Isn't the Primary Key a unique index?

Comment: Also, in the end of you answer, I didn't understand why there would be a difference in the order of link_type and URL?

Comment: @Phil This is a "composite" PK. It's a is **combination** of PAGE_ID and URL, which means there can be multiple URLs for the same page (and multiple pages for the same URL). In the ER diagrams, PK fields are listed in the "box" above the horizontal line that crosses the entity.

Comment: @Phil As for the order of the fields in the index - this is the consequence of how B-trees work. By keeping the {PAGE_ID, LINK_TYPE} at the **leading edge** of the index, and in **that specific order**, you are physically grouping rows that belong to the same page together, and rows that belong to the same type of the same page together, so rows don't need to be separately sorted by LINK_TYPE - DBMS gets them "pre-sorted" by simply doing the index range scan. Please take a look at the [Use The Index, Luke!](http://use-the-index-luke.com), for more in-depth explanation of how clustering works.

Answer (score 3):

You can get similar performances using a table for all objects, or one for links or websites. If you have two separate tables, doing a UNION of the results would return all of the results you needed.

The main reason to divide the results is whether they are really different (from your application point of view). That is, if you are going to end up using a lot of queries like

```
select * from objects where type='image';
```

then it might make sense to have two tables.

Then using group by is not a way of grouping the different results, it is a way of aggregating them.

So, for instance, you can use

```
select type, count(*) from objects group by type
```

to get

```
| image |  100000 |
| web   | 2000000 |
```

but it will not return the objects separated. To get them "grouped", you can either use a query for each one, or use an ordering and then have the logic in the application to divide the results.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how web data is close to img data. If data is basically made of the *link*, one table fits better, having a column to differentiate between web and data (and possibly others later, like css, js ...)

```
Links: (id, link, type)
```

adding an index on *type* or *type link* will help the grouping (by type), and the matching search by (type, link).

If however, web and img data are different in such a way that you don't want to mix apples and oranges, like

```
Web: (wid, wlink, rating, ...)
Img: (iid, ilink, width, height, mbsize, camera, datetaken, hasexif...)
```

in this case, besides the *link* both tables don't have much in common. Image links and web links being different, there is not even a "gain" when having a same link for both kinds of data. Another advantage (which is also possible with one table, but makes more sense here) is to link both kinds of data in another table

```
 Relations: (wid,iid)
```

that allows to maintain the relation between web sites and images, since an image may be used by several web sites, and web sites use several images. Indexing on `wid` and on `iid`.

My preference goes to the two tables (with optional Relations link).

Regarding queries from PHP, using `UNION` you can obtain the data from two tables in one query.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How much overhead would I have doing a union on two big tables?

Comment: All in all, doing only one query on two smaller tables, that collects the data from relevant rows (ie using one big table to get all data from both types without *union* would also return the empty fields of the other type), and the number of rows being the same, performance globally and memory or bandwidth wise, you should expect an improvement using *union* in that case. There is the overhead of *mysql* running two queries but, all in all, the *union* solution should be the winner - again - in that case.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I create two separate, smaller tables or one huge table?

Go for one table.

> What would be the most efficient way to subdivide the two types for presentation?

Depends on the *certain* search criteria.

Comment: YCS, Thanks for your answer. Could you explain what you mean by "Depends on the search criteria"?